# Chrome Custom Tabs - different default browser

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Is it possibly to use Chrome Custom Tabs in an app, even when a different browser is set as the default one? For example my default browser is Firefox, but my app should still open links in Chrome Custom Tabs.

Comment: Please check from ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429630/custom-chrome-tabs-asks-for-multiple-browser-to-choose ). The following question asked about "how to restrict custom tabs to bind only with Chrome Browser", it might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Be aware that Firefox is implementing support for Custom Tabs (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208655), and the Samsung Browser has it too. The user preferred browser should be used as much as possible.