# Android 11 Capture image using Camera

Tags: java, android, image, camera, capture

Documentation - https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

I have followed all the required steps to capture image using camera.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) { // its always null
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

`takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` - this line always returns null. and if i skip this check than camera opens but app crashes.

Comment: The `resolveActivity()` returning null is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535856/intent-resolveactivity-returns-null-in-api-30. We'd need to see the stack trace for the crash, though, if it's not related to that.

Answer (score 20):

Jaakko's answer is correct, and here is a quick explanation:

- Since API level 30, there have been changes in the package visibility. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility
- For your package manager to work properly, you need to declare `<queries>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

Code:

```
<manifest package="your.package.name">
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
</manifest>
```

This works only for the default camera apps. If your app is using some 3rd party camera, you can find some info here: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/16/action-image-capture-android-r.html

Comment: Thanks save my life!

Comment: But, that doesn't even ask for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_MEDIA permission !!!

Answer (score 5):

Add these to AndroidManifest.xml inside the manifest section:

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```