# Android: Email Intent ACTION_SENDTO doesn't work unless you add an intent filter

Tags: android, email, android-intent, gmail, intentfilter

I want to open Gmail with a preformatted email.
I am using this code:

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context, String receiverAddress, String title, String body) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { receiverAddress });
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    if (body != null) {
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    }
    if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        context.startActivity(emailIntent);
    }
}
```

However it works only if I add this `intent-filter` to the manifest file of my app:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

By doing this, it shows me an app selector with two apps: **my app** and **Gmail**.

However I don't want my app to be the receiver of this intent. I just want this intent received by Gmail (and other email clients).
But if I don't add that `intent-filter`, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62535856

Comment: I recommend removing the `resolveActivity()` call and replacing it with a `try`/`catch` around the `startActivity()` call. You need that `try`/`catch` anyway, as there may be other problems when starting an activity from another app. Also note that none of those extras are documented for `ACTION_SENDTO`, so not every app will honor them.

Comment: @CommonsWare you were right, by removing `resolveActivity()` the issue is gone. However I wonder why Android official documention says to use it: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email

Comment: Prior to Android 11, `resolveActivity()` wasn't a problem. That particular documentation page was not updated when Android 11 shipped.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following? This is what I use. As far as I can see your code is fine, and the chooser thing should not impact anything as such I feel, but still I would recommend to try the following once. It could be the chooser that is causing issue I feel.

```java
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

Comment: it seems I don't even need the `Intent.createChooser` line. I can just put at `try`/`catch` around the `startActivity`, as @CommonsWare suggested in his comment

Comment: Yes, that is one way too. Although I would suggest you use a chooser, you can supply it a message too if no app is matching and the common share sheet will handle it. @DanieleB

Answer (score 0):

I had the SENDTO intent-filter as this and my app was appearing in the list of email clients when startActivity called.

```
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
      </intent-filter>
```

I removed the mailto

```
 <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
 </intent-filter>
```

and my app stopped appearing in the list of mail clients.

I didn't change anything with resolveActivity or startActivity.