# How to join to a Zoom conference from Android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to implement an Android application to just quickly join to a Zoom conference.
I wrote the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("zoomus://join?action=join&confno=99999999999&pwd=ugnuiGOEIfgewigfweifcvewiofcewifcew"));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch(Exception e) {                
        }
    } else {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    }
    finish();
}
```

This code works nicely on my device and some others. But many users report that it doesn't work ("Error" toast). They click the app icon and nothing happens. The Zoom app is installed there.
Could you please help?

Comment: You have to also take care of the case when the `Zoom` application is not installed in the device.

Comment: In my case no need to check if Zoom is installed. All our users have it installed.

Comment: Well in that case, please provide with more details of the error.

Comment: what does `catch(Exception e) {}` do ?

Comment: I've edited the post. They get the "Error" toast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64204646/2240880

Added to AndroidManifest.xml after < /application> the following:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```