# When program is run the email app do not opens on mobile phone. OR when tried to modify code the app crashes

Tags: java, android, windows, email, android-intent

[image: Java Code for intent]

the email app is not opening on my android device. there are no error in code but don't know why app isn't working

Comment: Post actual code, not an image.  Especially here, the image is too small to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old or deprecated way to start activity for ACTION_SEND scenarios. Use below snippet for the correct way.

```
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
    type = "text/plain"
}

val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

You can check out the code snippet and detailed explanation here.
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#using-android-system-sharesheet

Answer (score 0):

Starting with API level 30, if you're targeting that version or higher, your app cannot see, or directly interact with, most external packages without explicitly requesting allowance.

Check this answer, it works for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166064/7248394