# How to make a google search string appear when you click a button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need the following logic: when I click a button, google search string opens up, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czVP3.gif)

I have the following in MainActivity:

```
        val mainBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.main_btn)

        mainBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH)
            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, no such app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

and the following in Manifest file:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some search query to the intent, it won't work without it.

```
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "some query")
```

If the `intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)` returns `null` try to add the `queries` block to your AndroidManifest before or after the `application` [(look here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535856/intent-resolveactivity-returns-null-in-api-30):

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: I added your line of code to mine right after the string
`val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH)`
But still does not work, I get a toast message from the Else block

Comment: solved the problem by adding Avitals code in MainActivity instead of my verification from the link you provided, now a google search string opens up with default query, but I would like to make as it is shown in my gif, other options I have not found yet

Comment: On API 32 it works almost like in your gif without default query, but on API 30 doesn't.