# Use Intent.resolveActivity to check if Waze app is exist in device is not working in Android 13 and above

Tags: android, mobile-development, android-package-managers, waze

I try to use this code to check if Waze app is in device, and it always returns false even if I have Waze in my device (it's in Android 13 and above).

```kotlin
fun isWazeExist(): Boolean {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://waze.com/ul?q=Hawaii")) 
    intent.setPackage("com.waze")
    intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager)?.let {
        true
    ?:let {
        false
    }
}
```

However if I change intent to Google Map URI and Package Name, the function is work.

```kotlin
fun isGoogleMapExist(): Boolean {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=bigcity")) 
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
    intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager)?.let {
        true
    ?:let {
        false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starting Android 11 you simply can't check that "some app" is installed (or obtain list of all installed apps), security and privacy reasons

more info [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility), [HERE](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535856/intent-resolveactivity-returns-null-in-api-30)

just guessing why you can check presence of Maps: because it's system app, pre-installed OR is set as default (for navi?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right. After I add QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permision, the result of this function is correct. I also need to update the policy declaration form when update app in Play Console.     

Thank you again!!!!