# Android Custom Tabs - prevent launchUrl() from opening default apps, force in-app custom tab browser

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

`.launchUrl(this@MainActivity, Uri.parse(url))`

When `url` is `https://www.amazon.com`, the Amazon app is opening instead of the custom tab browser. Is there any way to prevent this from happening and forcing to use the custom tab browser instead of default apps?

Comment: Interesting, but we have the opposite problem. 
We _want_ the Chrome Custom Tab to open the native app, but it doesn't (and there is no "Open in the app" menu item)

Comment: Does this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156787/is-it-possible-to-make-a-chrome-customtabs-intent-not-open-an-external-applicati ?

Answer (score 1):

If you add chrome package to the Custom Tabs intent it will open the custom tab instead of the app, i.e. `tabsIntent.intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");`
before calling `tabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse("https://www.amazon.com"));`

But will crash the app if Google Chrome is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/guide-get-started/#supporting-android-app-links):

> …passing a CustomTabsSession to a CustomTabIntent will force open the link in a Custom Tab, even if the corresponding native app is installed.

Following [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/guide-warmup-prefetch/), I came up with the following manager class:

```
class CustomTabSessionManager {

    private var mClient: CustomTabsClient? = null
    var mSession: CustomTabsSession? = null

    private val mConnection: CustomTabsServiceConnection = object : CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
        override fun onCustomTabsServiceConnected(
            name: ComponentName,
            client: CustomTabsClient
        ) {
            // Warm up the browser process
            client.warmup(0 /* placeholder for future use */)
            // Create a new browser session
            mSession = client.newSession(CustomTabsCallback())
            mClient = client
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
            mClient = null
            mSession = null
        }
    }

    fun bindCustomTabService(context: Context) {
        // Check for an existing connection
        if (mClient != null) {
            // Do nothing if there is an existing service connection
            return
        }

        // Get the default browser package name, this will be null if
        // the default browser does not provide a CustomTabsService
        val packageName = CustomTabsClient.getPackageName(context, null)
            ?: // Do nothing as service connection is not supported
            return
        CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(context, packageName, mConnection)
    }
}
```

And in my main Activity I do:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val customTabSessionManager = CustomTabSessionManager()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...

        customTabSessionManager.bindCustomTabService(this)
    }



    fun getCustomTabSession(): CustomTabsSession? = customTabSessionManager.mSession
}
```

You can then get the session whenever you want to open a custom tab:

```
val session = (requireActivity() as? MainActivity)?.getCustomTabSession()
CustomTabsIntent
   .Builder(session)
   .build()
   .launchUrl(requireContext(), "https://www.example.com/")
```

Do not forget to add the following to your Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  …
   <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```